# JavaScript print array result in same file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, arrays, frontend

I want to print a JavaScript array

```
data: [
          JSON.parse(genreCanvas.dataset.count).forEach(count => {
            `${count},\n`;
          })
      ],
```

to

```
data: [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          5,
      ],
```

like this but it's not working.

JavaScript seems to recognize it as an object. How can I do like this?

-- this is console.log result for genreCanvas.dataset.count --

[image: this is console.log result]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: What is `genreCanvas.dataset.count` here?

Comment: Please post example of genreCanvas.dataset structure.

Comment: You're messing with PHP style coding here, JS doesn't work like that. Use [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) to create a copy of an array.

Answer (score 0):

By having an object which is sttingifyable, you could stringify the data set with a spacer and get a formatted result.

```js
var data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

console.log(`data: ${JSON.stringify(data, null, 4)}`);
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you meant this?

```js
let data = `["2","3","4"]`
data = JSON.parse(data).map(count => +count)
console.log(data)
```